# Error “cordova\version is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file”

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

When i do command ionic cordova prepare android i receive  this error:

```
cordova\version"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12) {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '"C:\\Programacao\\appMalote216\\platforms\\android\\cordova\\version"'
}
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

I had this issue when trying to meet Google Play's new API level targeting policy. When I create the android@9 platform I can run the command normally and even generate a signed apk, when I add the android@10 platform when I give the prepare command I get this error.

**Configuration of development environment:**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.18.1 (C:\Users\micro-85\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.9.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 20 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 1.5.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\micro-85\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v16.13.2 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 8.4.0
   OS                : Windows 10

Node:v16.13.2
NPM: 8.4.0
Gradle: 7.3.3
```

Similar issue:https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/725

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue on Windows. The problem is that Windows CMD does not recognise file platforms/android/cordova/version as a command even if it exists. (as it's a bash script).

1. **Solution 1**

You can fix it by creating a ***.bat*** file that will run node script version.

For example create .bat **platforms/android/cordova/version.bat** with the following content:

```
node %~dpnx0
```

2. **Solution 2**: if you have bash installed and have this error when you run the script with npm, you can configure npm to use git bash instead of Windows CMD.

   npm config set script-shell ""

For example

```
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

Comment: Nice ! First option worked for me !

Comment: tried with first solution. not working for me. got this error. ReferenceError: node is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Office\JNKEFRM_playstore\JNK_SDK31\platforms\android\cordova\version.bat:1:1)

Answer (score 0):

Wait I solved this!  just go into \android\cordova

and rename version to version.js

then run your build command again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while doing, "cordova platform add android". It was adding the platform but while importing the plugins i was getting the above error mentioned.

So the issue was, in my system the cordova was not installed Globally,

in you terminal type,
npm i -g cordova

and successful installation, remove the plugins folder manually.

and then run these two commands,

- cordova platform rm android
- cordova platform add android

that should resolve your issue!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be caused by the `cordova-plugin-add-swift-support` plugin. You may be referencing this, or one of the plugins you're using may be using Swift for its iOS native support. The problem occurs even if you don't actually build for iOS or install the iOS platform on Windows.

The problem occurs on Windows because it doesn't have 'shebang' support (file starting `#!` and a path to the file that would interpret the file). Instead Windows tries to use the filename extension to find an interpreter, and fails. The `version` file is actually Javascript, expected to be run by `node`. The add-swift-support plugin really only expects to be run on macOS.

Older versions of `cordova-android` created a `version.bat` alongside `version`.

Swift support was included in `cordova-ios` 5.0.0, but some plugins haven't caught up with this and still depend on the older, unmaintained plugin.

This issue is reported on GitHub: https://github.com/akofman/cordova-plugin-add-swift-support/issues/76 . A fork of the plugin is available which fixes the issue: https://github.com/akofman/cordova-plugin-add-swift-support/issues/76#issuecomment-1158775224